# DXTn texture support, no "Enable S3TC..." option

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am having the same problem as described [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1151336).

I'm looking for support for DXTn textures. I ran `worldwind` in terminal and got the following error message:

```
Aug 22, 2012 5:28:12 PM gov.nasa.worldwind.layers.TextureTile initializeTexture
SEVERE: Exception attempting to read texture file
javax.media.opengl.GLException: DXTn compressed textures not supported by this graphics card
```

---

I tried the suggested solution from [here](http://forum.worldwindcentral.com/sh...ad.php?p=45020)

```
sudo apt-get install driconf
driconf
```

Under "Image Quality" change "Enable S3TC ..." to Yes. Save.

---

The `driconf` solution did not fix the problem. There was no "Enable S3TC..." option in the Image Quality tab.

I think I am using Nouveau driver and I wonder if I should switch to the Nvidia driver?

- Computer: Dell Precision M6400
- Processor: Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T9550 @ 2.66GHz × 2 Ubuntu: 12.0.4 LTS
- Video Card: NVIDIA Quadro FX 2700M
- Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on NV94

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S3_Texture_Compression

> While S3 Graphics is no longer a competitor in the graphics
>   accelerator market, license fees are still levied and collected for
>   the use of S3TC technology, for example in game consoles and graphics
>   cards. The patent-encumbered status of S3TC and its wide use in
>   software, despite non-encumbered alternatives, have led to a de facto
>   requirement for OpenGL drivers to support it and **present a major
>   obstacle to open source implementations**.

Which explains why Nouveau driver does not support it. I guess you need to switch to the binary NVidia drivers.

Answer (score 2):

Otherwise:

[image]

..and tell `WorldWind` not to use S3 texture compression (`.dds` format) but rather PNG default texture format.

You can download the [sources](http://builds.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/worldwind-releases/2.0/builds/worldwind-2.0.0.zip) (SDK 2.0 now):

```
wget http://builds.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/worldwind-releases/2.0/builds/worldwind-2.0.0.zip
unzip worldwind-2.0.0.zip -d worldwind-2.0.0
```

Then apply the changes to the source files listed [here](http://www.trimslice.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=2218&sid=69a03790796dd381f7450bb76557cc79#p2218) and [here](http://www.trimslice.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=2219#p2219).

Since those links are a little outdated, there are a few more changes you should apply in order to make things work on WW 2.0 release (see appendix).

Afterwards, you can re-build your new `worldwind.jar`:

```sh
cd worldwind-2.0.0/
ant worldwind.jarfile # or simply `ant'
```

I personally verified it by running the SDK from [Netbeans](http://worldwindcentral.com/wiki/WWJava_in_NetBeans_IDE#.280.5_SDK_era.29_Compiling_and_running_the_SDK_examples).

```sh
$ sudo lshw -C video | egrep "product|driver"
   product: RV635/M86 [Mobility Radeon HD 3670]
   configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
```

HTH

### APPENDIX: patch for SDK 2.0

```java
diff --git a/src/config/Earth/BMNGWMSLayer.xml b/src/config/Earth/BMNGWMSLayer.xml
--- a/src/config/Earth/BMNGWMSLayer.xml
+++ b/src/config/Earth/BMNGWMSLayer.xml
@@ -19,12 +19,12 @@
     <!-- day month year hours:minutes:seconds timezone -->
     <LastUpdate>26 03 2009 00:00:00 GMT</LastUpdate>
     <DataCacheName>Earth/BMNGWMS/BMNG(Shaded + Bathymetry) Tiled - Version 1.1 - 5.2004</DataCacheName>
-    <ImageFormat>image/dds</ImageFormat>
+    <ImageFormat>image/png</ImageFormat>
     <AvailableImageFormats>
         <ImageFormat>image/png</ImageFormat>
         <ImageFormat>image/dds</ImageFormat>
     </AvailableImageFormats>
-    <FormatSuffix>.dds</FormatSuffix>
+    <FormatSuffix>.png</FormatSuffix>
     <NumLevels count="5" numEmpty="0"/>
     <TileOrigin>
         <LatLon units="degrees" latitude="-90" longitude="-180"/>
diff --git a/src/config/Earth/BMNGWMSLayer2.xml b/src/config/Earth/BMNGWMSLayer2.xml
--- a/src/config/Earth/BMNGWMSLayer2.xml
+++ b/src/config/Earth/BMNGWMSLayer2.xml
@@ -22,7 +22,7 @@
         <ImageFormat>image/jpeg</ImageFormat>
         <ImageFormat>image/png</ImageFormat>
     </AvailableImageFormats>
-    <FormatSuffix>.dds</FormatSuffix>
+    <FormatSuffix>.png</FormatSuffix>
     <NumLevels count="5" numEmpty="0"/>
     <TileOrigin>
         <LatLon units="degrees" latitude="-90" longitude="-180"/>
diff --git a/src/config/Earth/CountryBoundariesLayer.xml b/src/config/Earth/CountryBoundariesLayer.xml
--- a/src/config/Earth/CountryBoundariesLayer.xml
+++ b/src/config/Earth/CountryBoundariesLayer.xml
@@ -21,7 +21,7 @@
     <AvailableImageFormats>
diff --git a/src/config/Earth/MSVirtualEarthHybridLayer.xml b/src/config/Earth/MSVirtualEarthHybridLayer.xml
--- a/src/config/Earth/MSVirtualEarthHybridLayer.xml
+++ b/src/config/Earth/MSVirtualEarthHybridLayer.xml
@@ -19,7 +19,7 @@
     <AvailableImageFormats>
         <ImageFormat>image/jpg</ImageFormat>
     </AvailableImageFormats>
-    <FormatSuffix>.dds</FormatSuffix>
+    <FormatSuffix>.jpg</FormatSuffix>
     <NumLevels count="16" numEmpty="4"/>
     <TileOrigin>
         <LatLon units="degrees" latitude="-90" longitude="-180"/>
@@ -40,4 +40,4 @@
     </Sector>
     <ActiveAltitudes max="1000e3"/>
     <UseTransparentTextures>true</UseTransparentTextures>
diff --git a/src/config/Earth/MSVirtualEarthRoadsLayer.xml b/src/config/Earth/MSVirtualEarthRoadsLayer.xml
--- a/src/config/Earth/MSVirtualEarthRoadsLayer.xml
+++ b/src/config/Earth/MSVirtualEarthRoadsLayer.xml
@@ -19,7 +19,7 @@
     <AvailableImageFormats>
         <ImageFormat>image/jpg</ImageFormat>
     </AvailableImageFormats>
-    <FormatSuffix>.dds</FormatSuffix>
+    <FormatSuffix>.jpg</FormatSuffix>
     <NumLevels count="16" numEmpty="4"/>
     <TileOrigin>
         <LatLon units="degrees" latitude="-90" longitude="-180"/>
@@ -40,4 +40,4 @@
     </Sector>
     <ActiveAltitudes max="1000e3"/>
     <UseTransparentTextures>true</UseTransparentTextures>
diff --git a/src/config/Earth/ScankortDenmarkImageLayer.xml b/src/config/Earth/ScankortDenmarkImageLayer.xml
--- a/src/config/Earth/ScankortDenmarkImageLayer.xml
+++ b/src/config/Earth/ScankortDenmarkImageLayer.xml
@@ -16,12 +16,12 @@
     <!-- day month year hours:minutes:seconds timezone -->
     <LastUpdate>25 06 2009 22:45:32 GMT</LastUpdate>
     <DataCacheName>Earth/Scankort Denmark</DataCacheName>
-    <ImageFormat>image/dds</ImageFormat>
+    <ImageFormat>image/png</ImageFormat>
     <AvailableImageFormats>
         <ImageFormat>image/png</ImageFormat>
         <ImageFormat>image/dds</ImageFormat>
     </AvailableImageFormats>
-    <FormatSuffix>.dds</FormatSuffix>
+    <FormatSuffix>.png</FormatSuffix>
     <NumLevels count="16" numEmpty="0"/>
     <TileOrigin>
         <LatLon units="degrees" latitude="-90" longitude="-180"/>
@@ -46,4 +46,4 @@
             <Time units="milliseconds" value="30000"/>
         </ReadTimeout>
     </RetrievalTimeouts>
diff --git a/src/config/Earth/USDANAIPWMSImageLayer.xml b/src/config/Earth/USDANAIPWMSImageLayer.xml
--- a/src/config/Earth/USDANAIPWMSImageLayer.xml
+++ b/src/config/Earth/USDANAIPWMSImageLayer.xml
@@ -17,12 +17,12 @@
     <!-- day month year hours:minutes:seconds timezone -->
     <LastUpdate>23 04 2009 17:55:00 GMT</LastUpdate>
     <DataCacheName>Earth/USDA NAIP</DataCacheName>
-    <ImageFormat>image/dds</ImageFormat>
+    <ImageFormat>image/png</ImageFormat>
     <AvailableImageFormats>
         <ImageFormat>image/png</ImageFormat>
         <ImageFormat>image/dds</ImageFormat>
     </AvailableImageFormats>
-    <FormatSuffix>.dds</FormatSuffix>
+    <FormatSuffix>.png</FormatSuffix>
     <NumLevels count="15" numEmpty="6"/>
     <TileOrigin>
         <LatLon units="degrees" latitude="-90" longitude="-180"/>
@@ -51,4 +51,4 @@
             <Time units="milliseconds" value="30000"/>
         </ReadTimeout>
     </RetrievalTimeouts>
diff --git a/src/gov/nasa/worldwind/layers/BasicTiledImageLayer.java b/src/gov/nasa/worldwind/layers/BasicTiledImageLayer.java
--- a/src/gov/nasa/worldwind/layers/BasicTiledImageLayer.java
+++ b/src/gov/nasa/worldwind/layers/BasicTiledImageLayer.java
@@ -190,7 +190,7 @@ public class BasicTiledImageLayer extends TiledImageLayer implements BulkRetriev
             params.setValue(AVKey.TILE_HEIGHT, 512);

         if (params.getValue(AVKey.FORMAT_SUFFIX) == null)
-            params.setValue(AVKey.FORMAT_SUFFIX, ".dds");
+            params.setValue(AVKey.FORMAT_SUFFIX, ".png");

         if (params.getValue(AVKey.NUM_LEVELS) == null)
             params.setValue(AVKey.NUM_LEVELS, 19); // approximately 0.1 meters per pixel
diff --git a/src/gov/nasa/worldwind/layers/rpf/RPFTiledImageLayer.java b/src/gov/nasa/worldwind/layers/rpf/RPFTiledImageLayer.java
--- a/src/gov/nasa/worldwind/layers/rpf/RPFTiledImageLayer.java
+++ b/src/gov/nasa/worldwind/layers/rpf/RPFTiledImageLayer.java
@@ -265,7 +265,7 @@ public class RPFTiledImageLayer extends TiledImageLayer
         if (params.getValue(AVKey.TILE_HEIGHT) == null)
             params.setValue(AVKey.TILE_HEIGHT, 512);
         if (params.getValue(AVKey.FORMAT_SUFFIX) == null)
-            params.setValue(AVKey.FORMAT_SUFFIX, ".dds");
+            params.setValue(AVKey.FORMAT_SUFFIX, ".png");
         if (params.getValue(AVKey.NUM_LEVELS) == null)      
             params.setValue(AVKey.NUM_LEVELS, 14); // approximately 0.5 meters per pixel
         if (params.getValue(AVKey.NUM_EMPTY_LEVELS) == null)
```

Answer (score 0):

After the WorldWind model is created, and before the window is displayed, you can loop through all the layers and force them to not use DDS for storing tile textures:

```
// Before the WorldWind window displays (which triggers the data retrievers)
// loop through the levels for each tiled image layer and mutate any level
// constructed to use DDS to instead use JPG (best compression) or PNG (best
// quality, but much larger files).
String cacheFormat = "jpg"; // could load this via configuration file
for (Layer layer : model.getLayers()) {
    if (layer instanceof BasicTiledImageLayer && ((BasicTiledImageLayer)layer).getTextureFormat() == null) {
        ((BasicTiledImageLayer)layer).setTextureFormat("image/" + cacheFormat);
        ((BasicTiledImageLayer)layer).setValue(AVKey.FORMAT_SUFFIX, "." + cacheFormat);
        ArrayList<Level> levels = ((BasicTiledImageLayer) layer).getLevels().getLevels();
        for (int i = 0; i < levels.size(); i++) {
            Level level = levels.get(i);
            if (level.getFormatSuffix().equals(".dds")) {
                AVList params = level.getParams();
                params.setValue(AVKey.FORMAT_SUFFIX, "." + cacheFormat);
                levels.set(i, new Level(params));
            }
        }
    }
}
```